# Can someone help me find the error in this procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to know where is the mistake in this procedure

```
set serveroutput on 
create or replace procedure insert_table(column_name in varchar2, dat in varchar2)
as
    table_name varchar2(100):= column_name || '_' || dat;
    sql_create varchar2(100) := 'create table '||table_name||'(FIRSTNAME varchar2(100))';
    sql_str varchar2(100);
    CURSOR c_emp is 
    select FIRSTNAME 
    from employees
    where column_name = dat;
begin
    execute immediate sql_create;
    for r_reg in c_emp
    loop
    sql_str:='INSERT INTO '||table_name||'('''||r_reg.firstname||''')';
    execute immediate sql_str;
    end loop;
end;
/
execute insert_table('CITY','London');
```

Edit:
Ok i add the correction mentioned below in the syntax error, but how can I do so that the parameter of the column name can be taken at the cursor, because for now it is of type varchar and 'CITY' should be a row name.

Comment: On a side note: I hope this is just a practice or a temporary thing. You should of course not create tables from data in a database.

Comment: Since you are dealing with dynamic queries, I think sometimes is better to print out the queries and make sure they work by executing them so you shall know that errors (if you will have in the future) are not SQL syntax errors. Also, you should not forget to commit after creating and inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `dynamic query` in the cursor as follows. Also, you missed `VALUES` keyword in the `INSERT` statement which I have added (Please see inline comment in the codes)

**Oracle sample data creation:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEES" (
  2      "ID"           NUMBER,
  3      "FIRSTNAME"    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  4      "CITY"         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  5      PRIMARY KEY ( "ID" ) USING INDEX ENABLE
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

**Now, Let's create your procedure**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_TABLE (
  2      COLUMN_NAME   IN            VARCHAR2,
  3      DAT           IN            VARCHAR2
  4  ) AS
  5
  6      TABLE_NAME   VARCHAR2(100) := COLUMN_NAME || '_' || DAT;
  7      SQL_CREATE   VARCHAR2(100) := 'create table ' || TABLE_NAME || '(FIRSTNAME varchar2(100))';
  8      C_EMP        SYS_REFCURSOR; -- declaration of cursor
  9      LV_FNAME     EMPLOYEES.FIRSTNAME%TYPE; -- to store the each value from cursor
 10  BEGIN
 11      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CREATE;
 12      OPEN C_EMP FOR 'SELECT FIRSTNAME
 13                        FROM EMPLOYEES
 14                       WHERE ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' = ''' || DAT || '''';
 15      -- above statement used dynamic query in cursor
 16      LOOP
 17          FETCH C_EMP INTO LV_FNAME;
 18          EXIT WHEN C_EMP%NOTFOUND;
 19          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || TABLE_NAME || ' VALUES (''' || LV_FNAME || ''')'; -- added VALUES keyword in INSERT statement.
 20      END LOOP;
 21
 22      COMMIT;
 23  END INSERT_TABLE;
 24  /
```

**Let's execute it and see the result now.**

```
SQL>
SQL> EXECUTE INSERT_TABLE('CITY', 'London');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM CITY_LONDON;

FIRSTNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEJASH

SQL>
```

Ohh Yes, It created the desired table and also data is populated correctly.

Cheers!!

Comment: OMG you are awesome, thnks a lot!! that really helped me, thnks thnks. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes. This

```
sql_str:='INSERT INTO '||table_name||'('||r_reg.firstname||');';
```

should be

```
sql_str:='INSERT INTO '||table_name||'('''||r_reg.firstname||''');';
```

This will turn `INSERT INTO CITY_London (Peter);` into `INSERT INTO CITY_London ('Peter');`.

And according to the docs (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm):

> When constructing a single SQL statement in a dynamic string, do not include a semicolon (;) at the end inside the quotation mark.

So the two SQL strings for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` should be:

```
sql_create varchar2(100) := 'create table ' || table_name || '(FIRSTNAME varchar2(100))';
```

and

```
sql_str := 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || '(''' || r_reg.firstname || ''')';
```

Comment: That helped to execute the program, but it doesn't give me results, I think it's because a column name like varchar2 ('City') is being passed but I don't know how to make the cursor query take it into account.

Comment: No exception? I suppose the only problem then is that your not committing your inserts. Add `commit;` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is the answer for your last question. You can pass parameters to the cursor like there:

```
declare
    CURSOR c_emp(p_param varchar2) is 
    select p_param val
    from dual;
begin
    for r_reg in c_emp('b')
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(r_reg.val);
    end loop;
end;
```